# Symfony 2 yaml to XML

Tags: php, xml, symfony, service, yaml

how to write this in XML?

```
# src/Acme/MainBundle/Resources/config/services.yml
services:
    acme_main.menu_builder:
        class: Acme\MainBundle\Menu\MenuBuilder
        arguments: ["@knp_menu.factory"]

    acme_main.menu.main:
        class: Knp\Menu\MenuItem # the service definition requires setting the class
        factory_service: acme_main.menu_builder
        factory_method: createMainMenu
        arguments: ["@request"]
        scope: request # needed as we have the request as a dependency here
        tags:
            - { name: knp_menu.menu, alias: main } # The alias is what is used to retrieve the menu
```

I have tried it but getting the next error:
xml:

```
<!-- Knp Menu -->
<service id="acme.menu_builder" class="Acme\FrontendBundle\Menu\MenuBuilder">
    <argument type="service" id="knp_menu.factory" />
    <argument type="service" id="security.context" />
</service>

<service id="acme.menu.main" class="Acme\Menu\MenuItem" scope="request">
    <argument type="service" id="acme_menu.menu_builder" />
    <argument type="service" id="request" />
    <tag name="knp_menu.menu" alias="main" method="createMainMenu" />
</service>
```

error:
`ErrorException: Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 2 passed to Knp\Menu\MenuItem::__construct() must implement interface Knp\Menu\FactoryInterface, instance of Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request given`

Comment: You can convert this automatically now with the third party [Symfony2 Service Config Converter](http://converter.rosstuck.com/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Where did you get the XML format from? It looks like some completely different setting (for instance, the `acme.menu_builder` has the `Acme\MainBundle\Menu\MenuBuilder` class in yaml and the `Acme\FrontendBundle\Menu\MenuBuilder` in xml. And the `acme.menu_builder` service has 1 argument in yaml and 2 in xml?

To answer your question, it should look something like this:

```xml
<services>
    <service id="acme_main.menu_builder" 
        class="Acme\MainBundle\Menu\MenuBuilder"
    >
        <argument type="service" id="knp_menu.factory" />
    </service>

    <service id="acme_main.menu.main"
        class="Knp\Menu\MenuItem"
        factory-service="acme_main.menu_builder"
        factory-method="createMainMenu"
        scope="request"
    >
        <argument type="service" id="request" />
        <tag name="knp_menu.menu" alias="main" />
    </service>
</services>
```